# WiX 4 Component Condition - RegistrySearch

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix4

I'm trying to implement a condition for a component. If a certain registry Key/Value exists the component should be installed, otherwise it shouldn't.
The RegistrySearch part works fine.
But the condition attribute itself shows no effect. I've checked the log file as well and there isn't any entry containing the condition.

I've seen this post as well, but unfortunately it didn't help [WIX v4 Cannot make a component condition based on RegistrySearch Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016836/wix-v4-cannot-make-a-component-condition-based-on-registrysearch-property/75026894#75026894)

My code so far:

```html
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Package
             Name="WpfAppPackage"
             Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer"
             Version="1.0.0.0"
             UpgradeCode="32058e2f-46ed-4823-9795-d68433888c7f">
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
        
        
      <Property Id="MASTERKEYPROPERTY">
          <RegistrySearch Id="MasterKeySearch" Root="HKLM" Name="pc" Type="raw" Key="SOFTWARE\TODOManufacturer\WpfAppPackage"/>
      </Property>

        <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents"
                        Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
            <Component Guid="e0f20e79-858d-4ee5-a5c0-53595283a7f0" Condition="MASTERKEYPROPERTY=&quot;_571E721F-2F6C-4604-9898-1FD2B5FE9BF6&quot;"> <!-- Underscore for a missmatch-->
                <File Source="WpfApp.exe" />
                <File Source="WpfApp.dll" />
                <File Source="WpfApp.runtimeconfig.json" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>

        <Feature Id="Main">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Package>
</Wix>
```

Here is an extract from my log.
It includes all lines with the component ID and the property change entry for the MASTERKEYPROPERTY

```
134 MSI (c) (B0:30) [08:21:27:789]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MASTERKEYPROPERTY property. Its value is '571E721F-2F6C-4604-9898-1FD2B5FE9BF6'.
695 MSI (s) (E0:B8) [08:21:55:089]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={E0F20E79-858D-4EE5-A5C0-53595283A7F0},,State=-7,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=1)
696 1: {6D3E895B-79CA-4DFD-9197-DDD4EA508912} 2: {E0F20E79-858D-4EE5-A5C0-53595283A7F0} 
xxx no Entry with the underscored reg Key
```

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: Yes, I've just edited the question. Is this helpful?

Comment: Whats with the _ mismatch?  Is that intentional?  Is your expectation for the component to get installed or not installed? Also, is this a new install or an upgrade?

Comment: The key itself exists without the underscore. The installation should be terminated if the key does not exists. Because of the underscore the condition should be evaluated as false and interrupt the installation. I expected the same behavior for updates too, but like I mentioned, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Your using a component condition.  That would only control the installation state of that component.  If you want to block the installer you have to use a Launch element.

```
  <Launch Condition="Installed OR MASTERKEYPROPERTY" Message="[ProductName] requires WpfAppPackage to be installed." />
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. At this point it does work for the whole installation. But I think my last comment was a bit unclear. I would like to control the installation component-wise